# Change folder icons on a usb device

Tags: scripts, icons

I want to change the folder icons that are on a USB device, so that you get the same look regardless of which machine you open it from.
Is this possible to do through a script that is automatically activated when the usb device is mounted.

Or can I solve it in another way.

to avoid misunderstandings I have more than 20 movies on a usb memory where each movie has its folder, they are these folder icons I want to somehow change so that they become unique regardless of which machine I mount the usb memory on.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu?

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04 up to 20.10